# How to navigate in XAML using a string as an argument to this.Frame.Navigate(typeof()?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uinavigationcontroller, windows-store-apps

in Xaml file I have

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="50,50,50,50" FontSize="50" SelectionChanged="NavigateKing">
        <ComboBoxItem></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Prince Wijaya"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Pandukabhaya"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Dewanampiya Tissa"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

And in Xaml.Cs file

```
private void NavigateKing(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem);
        string navigatingURI = cbi.Content.ToString();
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(/*IntendedXaml filename should be here*/);
    }
```

Rather than writing a whole if-else or switch-case scenario can I just pass the NavigationURI to navigate?

Comment: You could store the actual type on the `Tag` property of the `ComboBoxItem` and use the `Tag` for the `SelectedItem` to navigate.

Comment: @JeffBridgman can u please give an example please

Comment: Unfortunately not. I don't have any experience with XAML, but I've done similar things in WinForms and saw that the `Tag` property existed so assumed it was possible.

Comment: We can do that with `this.Navigate(//URI goes here)` but unfortunately in Windows 8 apps only `this.Frame.Navigate()` available..

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

XAML

```
<ComboBox Margin="50,50,50,50" FontSize="50" SelectionChanged="NavigateKing">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Prince Wijaya" Tag="BlankPage1"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Pandukabhaya" Tag="BlankPage2"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Dewanampiya Tissa" Tag="BlankPage3"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

C#

```
private void NavigateKing(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem);
    string navigatingURI = cbi.Content.ToString();
    this.Frame.Navigate(Type.GetType(this.GetType().Namespace + "." + cbi.Tag.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Above code it giving me an exception, object not referenced like one

Comment: NullReferenceException at in this line this.Frame.Navigate(Type.GetType(this.GetType().Namespace + "." + cbi.Tag.ToString()));
}

didn't I mention that all the XAML's reside inside a folder called Pages?